# C multidimensional array of strings

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

I'm declaring an array of strings very simply, hard-coded, but it keeps giving me the `array type has incomplete element type` error.

I guess this has something to do with the length of each array but I don't know how to fix it without setting a fixed length for the strings.

```
char allocate[][2][] = {  // Error with or without the 2
    {"value1","value2"},
    {"value3","value4"}
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That syntax isn't valid.  If you want a true multi-dimensional array, all the dimensions must be specified, except the first one.  (The compiler must know how big the "inner" arrays are in order to perform address calculation for the outer dimensions.)

Try this instead:

```
const char *allocate[][2] = {
    {"value1","value2"},
    {"value3","value4"}
};
```

It declares a 2D array of `const char *`.

Note that if you want strings that you can *write* to, then the above approach will not work.

Comment: So this array contains pointers to strings (Which are then stored outside the array?) Wouldn't you be able to write to the strings if you removed the `const` keyword?

Comment: @J V: No, that's undefined behaviour (although typically you'll get a seg-fault).  String literals are read-only, and really should always be pointed to by a `const char *`.  The only reason C allows you to use a `char *` is for some backwards compatibility issues.